# How to rearrange a single row into multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, symbols, bit

I have one array of zeros and ones in one row like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb7Oz.png]

But I want to rearrange them to look like this, every 5 bits in one row:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uliOd.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with Office 365:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,SEQUENCE(INT(COUNT($1:$1)/5),5))
```

The result will spill.

[image]

with older versions use:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,((ROW($ZZ1)-1)*5)+COLUMN(A$1))
```

Copy over five columns and down till you get all `0`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Copy each set of cells that you want to rearrange from row to column format, special paste and make sure to check the box "transpose".

Comment: No, the OP does not want to transform one row to one column.